# Can Catapult's target be in an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

Can I use Catapult to hurt an Archmage who is in his Antimagic Field?

Antimagic Field:

> Target: Self
>   Range 10 feet

Catapult's trajectory is quite unnatural:

> The object flies in a **straight line** up to 90 feet in a direction you choose before falling to the ground

This makes me think that magic does not just fling it, but it is working on it until impact.
However, it could also be just a simplification on the creator's part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible, as long as the object you choose is located outside the antimagic field.

> **Targeted Effects.** Spells and other magical effects, such as
>   majic missile and charm person, that target a creature  or an object in the sphere  have no effect on that target.

Catapult spell is instantaneous, the only magic is used on the object to launch it in chosen direction. It is not concentration sustained as telekinesis. According to the description, the projectile stops if it impacts against a solid surface. It is not a magical effect  but pure physical force.

Still, if the caster would be able to cast 8th-leveI abjuration spell, a simple wall of force in a shape of dome, located just outside the antimagic field.

The answer from Wizards of the coast:

> Thank you for contacting Wizards of the Coast. As long as the spell is within the weight limits. The spell is not a continuous spell it is a one time spell that launches a object. If you have any questions or concerns please feel free to contact us again at your earliest convenience.

Comment: What question is the quote from WotC asnwering exactly? I do not understand why the weight limit and whether it is continous is relevant to András' question.

Comment: For this case, would it deal mundane bludgeoning rather than magical bludgeoning with regard to creatures resistant to non-magical bludgeoning?

Comment: The spell *catapult* specifically describes a **creature** who fails a Dexterity saving throw as "the target".