Does the Cube of Force only block ranged spell attacks when using Face 4 "Spell effect" blocking?
I'd like to understand the Cube of Force's applications and restrictions when it comes to Face 4: "Spell effects can't pass through the barrier" (DMG page 160). I take this to mean that it will block ranged spell attacks, like a Fire Bolt, since that spell is described as "You hurl a mote of fire at a creature or object within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target" (PHB page 242) thus it would need to pass through the barrier and would therefore be blocked.
Since the Cube of Force seems to only block spell effects passing through the barrier, my assumption is that many spells which are not ranged attacks can be cast on the bearer of the cube as long as they don't pass through the barrier.
Here is one example:
Bigby's Hand: (PHB page 218) "You create a Large hand of shimmering, translucent force in an unoccupied space that you can see within range."
In the following community post (relating to "Wall of Force"), the community supported the notion (with reference to Teleportation) that Teleportation could completed since the character was not passing through the barrier:
Does the Wall of Force spell block teleportation?
In a second community post (also relating to "Wall of Force"), the commentary indicates that "A spell that its effect starts at a point you can see within range can be cast on the other side of a Wall of Force.":
Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?
Thus, I would like to know if it's correct to assume that this spell can be cast at the bearer of a Cube of Force using Face 4 since it does not seem to require passing through the barrier?

Does this need the AL Tag?

Are you asking this question in the context of an AL game? The AL tag is for questions where the specific rules for AL should be considered when answering.

Thanks for the tip, AL tag removed

After additional review of earlier posts on the topic, I found my question to be quite similar to this one: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190894/what-counts-as-a-spell-effect-for-purposes-of-side-4-of-a-cube-of-force Please go ahead and close my question, and thank-you for the contributions provided!

There is no such distinction.
The Cube of Force blocks spell effects, regardless on the fact that the caster has to make a ranged spell attack, or induces a saving throw to resist to the effect(s), or even another mechanics describes how the target(s) is(are) affected, such as in the Sleep spell case.
All the spells listed in the question are blocked by the barrier.

Then how do you account for Misty Step or Teleport, which according to community feedback, are not blocked by the barrier?

@Maadiah that is not a spell effect that affects the user of the cube, maybe. Can you point to the Q&A regarding what you said?

yes, here is the link:https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72553/does-the-wall-of-force-spell-block-teleportation

@Maadiah that's Wall of force, the spell, not Cube of Force the item.

I'm not sure why they would follow different mechanics, since the Wall of Force produces "an invisible wall of force" and the Cube of Force produces "a barrier of invisible force" and the argumentation in that link points to the notion of "physically passing through the wall"

@Maadiah they follow different mechanics because it is written so in the description.
