Can a Cube of Force be used to end spell effects when entering an area as opposed to being cast into the cube area?
According to the Dungeon Master's Guide P. 160, when using Face 4 of the Cube of Force: "Spell effects can't pass through the barrier."
Does this mean that when a character enters an area with a magical effect active (as opposed to having a magical effect cast into the area of the cube) that it will cancel the effect?
Here are two examples:

My character's ally, who is 20 feet away, fails his save versus Charm Person. If my character using the Cube of Force (Face 4) walks up to him and one of the walls of the cube passes through him, will the spell be negated?

A hostile Mage, who is 20 feet away, casts a spell requiring concentration, such as Cloudkill.
If my character walks up to the Mage as per the previous example, will the concentration spell also be negated?


Thanks for your input!

Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/190894/85326

Thanks Honey Battery, I reformulated the question to more effectively differentiate it from that related topic.

The dupe answers to a similar problem, but with a different game feature, the Wall of Force spell, while here the magic item Cube of Force is considered, which presents a different description text.

Related, but not a duplicate, since the wording for Tiny Hut is not identical: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137020/40516

The description is quite foggy, it needs a DM ruling.
The description of this item leaves a lot of room for DM's interpretation and ruling: other game features are more precise1 in their description, such as Dispel Magic or Antimagic Field, while just writing

Spell effects can't pass through the barrier.

needs some DM work.
On concentration spells.
The description of the item does not report anything that makes think that the spell ends or the concentration is broken once the caster concentrating on a spell enters the AoE of the Cube of Force. Hence, the effects are negated, but the concentration still holds, unless it is broken in some other ways (e.g., by damaging the caster who then lose the concentration saving throw).
On AoE spells.
In the example of the Cloudkill spell, one has to consider the position of the bearer of the Cube with respect to the effect taking place and to the timing of the Cube activation.
If the Cube's user is outside the current 20 ft. radius circle area of the AoE of Cloudkill and the Cube is already active, when they walk into the fog created by the spell such fog is kept at bay and cannot pass the barrier.
If the Cube's user activates the 4th face of the item while inside the AoE of Cloudkill, two possible cases may arise:

The fog is pushed away, since (emphasis mine):


a barrier of invisible force springs into existence, forming a cube 15 feet on a side.

A strict reading suggests that the barrier pushes away the fog, since to originates from the caster and it grows until it reaches its full size.

A portion of fog inside the AoE of the Cube remains there, since the barrier appears instantaneously at its full size, including some part of the fog inside its AoE.

A DM has to decide which interpretation works at their table. For what is worth, I prefer the first one since the verb springs into existence and the shape of the barrier (a cube) makes me imagine a barrier originating from the magic item itself and then expanding.
On magical effects active on creatures.
If a creature suffers (or benefits) from a magical effect, once they try to enter the Cube's AoE such magical effect is blocked by the barrier. Can the creature move close to the Cube's bearer? In the description nothing prevents it, indeed a creature with a magical effect is still a creature, not a magical effect.
Recall that the spell affecting a creature does not end. Compare the text of the Dispel Magic spell:

Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

In this case, it seems more that the effect is suppressed, as it happens in the case of Antimagic Field. But since this is not clearly stated, the DM has to make a ruling.

1 Which still bring a lot of questions...

So . . . once the charmed creature passes the barrier, spell effect being suppressed as it crosses, does the spell effect spring back into existance?

@Jack Since the spell does not end, it seems so, but the DM has to make a ruling since it is not stated in an explicit manner.

I definitely agree with you that is it not very clear!  I mean . . . just like the cube doesn't kill living things within its boundaries, once within the cube, do spell effects bounce back?

@Jack my reading is that the effects are suppressed: the charmed creature enters the cube AoE, the spell is suppressed and they are not under the influence of Charm Person: they exit the barrier and the Charm Person is still there

Understood.  As is often the case, the ambiguity is a bit frustrating . . . .

No, the Cube of Force does not end spell effects
There is no language in the cube description that suggests that it ends spell effects.  The Description says:

If your movement causes the barrier to come into contact with a solid object that can't pass through the cube, you can't move any closer to that object as long as the barrier remains.

And Face 4 says:

Spell effects can't pass through the barrier.

Being charmed is a spell effect, so your ally can't enter
And so, your charmed ally in your example #1, can't pass through the barrier created by Face 4.
Here's the challenge:  the item description does not say what happens if something with a spell effect upon it tries to move past the barrier of Face 4.
Examples and specifics aren't given, so the DM needs to interpret, but to my reading, when barrier created by Face 4 encounters your ally, the ally themselves cannot enter the barrier.  In such as case, the DM could reasonably interpret that a strength contest could result as your character pushes the barrier against your ally, if your ally chooses to push back, or more of a shove contest if your ally doesn't resist.
The DM could rule that the barrier created by Face 4 somehow pushes the charmed condition off your ally, but there is no language in the text of the item that supports that.
That would also mean that Face 3 works differently:

Living matter can’t pass through the barrier.

Face 3 doesn't remove the quality of being living, it just keeps the living matter out.  If the Face 4 barrier suppresses spell effects, that's working differently.  And that's okay.  There's plenty about this item that is unclear, and it's reasonable for a DM to interpret as best suits them.
An alternative interpretation - the barrier somehow suppresses or removes a spell effect
Given the lack of clarity, the DM needs to interpret.  I believe the most reasonable interpretation, given above, is that a creature bearing a spell effect can't pass the barrier.
However, the alternative, the barrier somehow suppresses or removes a spell effect, is not completely unreasonable.
It is confusing, though.  The language says a thing can't pass the barrier, it doesn't say the thing can't exist on the caster's side of the barrier.  It does not seem reasonable that gases or living creatures cannot exist within the cube.  It also doesn't seem reasonable that spell effects on the caster are suppressed.  So, to my reading, the most reasonable interpretation is that a creature bearing a spell effect can't enter.
So, the DM needs to decide which interpretation seems the most reasonable.
Concentrating on a spell is not a spell effect, so the hostile mage's concentration is not affected
Spell areas of effect are fairly well defined, not that there aren't plenty of questions about them.
The basic rules say:

A spell's description specifies its area of effect, which typically has one of five different shapes: cone, cube, cylinder, line, or sphere.

And cloudkill says:

You create a 20-foot-radius sphere of poisonous, yellow-green fog centered on a point you choose within range.

It is clear that the sphere of poisonous fog is cloudkill's effect, not the concentration of the mage.
The DM would need to interpret what happens when the barrier created by Face 4 encounters the sphere of poisonous fog, but since the fog "spreads around corners" it is reasonable to assume that the fog is pushed by the barrier.
There's plenty of room for DM interpretation
The Cube of Force doesn't give a lot of detail about exactly how it works, and there isn't much else that works like it in the game, and so even trying to follow RAW very closely, the DM will likely need to interpret the results of using the Cube of Force in many situations.

Hi Jack The -1 wasn't mine by the way. I wish people actually put in a comment for down-voting. I do have a question though. So, when would being charmed as per the spell Charm Person not be a spell effect? I don't get why qualify your statement with "reasonably" rather than simply saying it is a spell effect?

@Senmurv Hmmm.  Yeah, I think you have a good point.  I've removed the word reasonably.  Regarding the down vote . . . .  I find comments such as yours extremely useful, and thank you!  I find down-votes with an explanation also just as useful.  Down-votes without an explanation . . . less helpful.  The downvote button mouse hover says "This answer is not useful" -- okay . . . fine, but why not?  Myself, I hardly ever downvote any more, can't remember last time I did.  If I think there's room for improvement, if it's important enough to me, I say something, otherwise, I just move on.

My Dv is due to the Charmed effect: if a creature is under some spell effect, I do not see why they cannot enter, since "there is no language in the text of the item that supports that.", to quote the same answer. And the reasoning on the living matter does not hold.

@Eddymage  I'm not clear on what you're saying.  Are you saying the creature who is charmed via Charm Person is, yes, under a spell effect, and yes, can pass the barrier of Face 4, even though they are charmed?  Is your argument that the charmed effect is more or less pushed off the creature as they pass the barrier, like the OP suggests, or something else?

The barrier blocks spell effects, not creatures:  a creature with an active spell effect is still a creature. I think that the creature can pass, and the effect is suppressed, but a DM can decide otherwise, since it is not clearly stated.

@Eddymage  Hmm.  I'll think about that.

@Eddymage I've added language to address your point as an alternative interpretation.

It does not sound right to me still, and I do not think that the comparison with the passage about living matter is of any use, the phrase "could Face 3 somehow push being living off a target" seems to be a reading not supported by the rules.

@Eddymage  I tried to change the language a bit.  To me, matter that is living is kept out is parallel to matter with a spell effect on it is kept out.  But you are right, it is ambiguous.  I suspect the designers just thought about fireball and similar when they wrote Face 4, but we'll never know.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
